# FileExistAtPath return false

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager, avaudiorecorder

Ok I record an audio file using AVAudioRecorder.. When I done with recording the delegate method calls..

```
- (void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)avrecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag{
       filePathAudio = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",avrecorder.url];
       BOOL fileExist = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[avrecorder.url path]];
}
```

When I debug and check value of filePathAudio it shows

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E0B11F18-4607-402D-AE2C-B032F40E0ADF/MyApp.app/recordTest.WAV
```

and [avrecoder.url path] returns

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E0B11F18-4607-402D-AE2C-B032F40E0ADF/MyApp.app/recordTest.WAV
```

when I check 'fileExist' it show false.

Can someone help me with that I want to check file size that I record..

Comment: You are passing avrecorder.url to filePathAudio and then calls the latter a file path when in fact the dot notation says otherwise.

Comment: I am not getting you.. YES I am saving avrecorder.url in filePathAudio and checking if file exist by fileExistAtPath by passing [avrecorder.url path] <- it returns path.

Comment: The fine print of fileExistsAtPath: says you shouldn't check if the file exists.

Comment: Has the recording finished successfully? check with the "flag" value, if it is "NO" in that case file may not be available(just a guess!)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
BOOL fileExist = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[avrecorder.url path]];
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4, you can check the existence of a file at a URL path using the FileManager's fileExist function like the following.

```
var fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
fileURL?.appendPathComponent("file.txt")
let doesFileExist = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL?.path ?? "non-existent-file")
```

Here it is wrapped in AVAudioRecorderDelegate's function to match your code above for convenience.

```
import AVFoundation

class FancyViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

        func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
            let doesFileExist = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: recorder.url.path)
            print("The file at \(recorder.url.path) does \(doesFileExist ? "" : "not") exist.")
        }
 ...
```